# Spring Data REST, QueryDSL and HashMaps - Null Predicate from URL when referring to HashMap properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest, querydsl

I have an entity object that I'm persisting in MongoDB using Spring Data MongoDB and exposing a REST API to query it. The Entity looks like the following :

**Entity.java**

```
 @Document
 public class Entity {
      @Id
      String id;
      Map<String, String> properties;
   }
```

Corresponding Spring Data repository is as below. It leverages Spring Data MongoDB's integration with QueryDsl:

**EntityRepository.java**

```
public interface EntityRepository extends MongoRepository<Entity, String>
                                         ,QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Entity> {
}
```

Here's the controller through which I query the stored Entities:

**EntityController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/entities")
public class EntityController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EntityController.class);

    @Autowired
    EntityRepository entityRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Page<Entity> findAllEntities(Pageable pageable) throws ResourceQueryException {
        return entityRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/q")
    public Page<Entity> filterEntities(
            @QuerydslPredicate(root = Entity.class) Predicate predicate,
            Pageable pageable) {
        return entityRepository.findAll(predicate,pageable);
    }

}
```

When I hit the url `localhost:8080/entities/q?id=xxx` it works as expected. However, when I hit the url `localhost:8080/entities/q?properties.p1=v1` (query keys and values of the `Map` property), I get a null Predicate in my method, due to which all Entities are being returned.

How do I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

You should store your `properties` field as `List` of `key-value` pairs then it would be possible to search in it.

Your query should work with next structure:

```
{  id : "1233454",
   properties : [ 
        { "key : "key", "value" : "value" }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But while using this schema, it was getting difficult for querying objects with a specific property and I had to resort to the $elematch construct. Support for this in Spring Data Web appears to be severely lacking. I was facing issues while forming the Predicate object automatically from the URL, so I had to resort to the above mentioned Map<String, String> approach.

Comment: But actually you can write your customized binding like here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/web/querydsl Structure should like I've mentioned and query like 'properties.p1 = p2' should not work or it works for you from console for example?